# Add row "Type" based on winning product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'CustomerSales'. Customer buy multiple products regularly. I want to create a query that looks at all customers and selects the top selling product inserts a row with the name of the top selling product.

Example.

```
Customer-Product-Sales
Joe-1a $200
Joe-2a $10
Joe-3a $100
Alice-2a $400
Alice-3a $300
Alice-1a $50
Dawn-3a $1000
Dawn -2a $50
Dawn -1a $10
```

Given this data for example, I like to insert a row in my query that says that Joe's 'Top Product' is 1a, Alice is 2a, and Dawn is 3a.

Comment: Not nearly enough info. Please edit your question and include the table create statement and the SQL you have so far as well as the table  you want to update. If this is Homework, mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not really big, then the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick works very well:

```
select customer,
       substring_index(group_concat(product order by sales desc), ',', 1) as TopProduct
from t
group by customer;
```

Here is another approach without `group by`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sales = (select max(t2.sales) from t t2 where t2.customer = t.customer);
```

This issue with this approach is that products that are tied for first place will result in multiple rows in the output.  You can actually solve that by choosing an arbitrary one of them:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sales = (select t2.sales
                 from t t2
                 where t2.customer = t.customer
                 order by t2.sales desc
                 limit 1
                );
```

Comment: thanks but I get a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'" I checked and checked again the sequence.

Comment: `group_concat()` definitely supports `order by`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat.